# Decrypt ChaCha20-Poly1305 (8 Byte Nonce) in Dart

Tags: dart, encryption, libsodium, sodium

Poly1305 encrypted UDP-Stream from a web server with a 8 Byte Nonce. Is there a way to decrypt this in dart?
I tried these packages:

[sodium_libs](https://pub.dev/packages/sodium_libs) (accepted only XChaCha20-Poly1305-IETF / 24 Byte Nonce)

[pointycastle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) (accepted only ChaCha20-Poly1305-IETF / 12 Byte Nonce)

Is there any way to decrypt the classic ChaCha20-Poly1305 with a 8 Byte Nonce? It was possible with the old [flutter_sodium](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sodium) package, but this is deprecated

Comment: Have you tried padding it with 4 bytes zeros at the start/end to see if that works?

Comment: There's a PR on that old package that upgrades it to ffi 2. Why don't you download that and step through to see how it allows an 8 byte nonce and then apply the same logic to the other packages. (Or simply use the branch from the PR.)